# bash: X: Argument list too long

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a script, which is a loop that collects on each iteration sql request and sends it to the server.
Request look like `select a from b where c in (d) and e=f`

Since there are too many rows in d for one query, I parse it into parts, and it turns out that I execute the same query in several iterations: `select a from b where c in ("1", "2", "3 ") and e = f`, then `select a from b where c in (" 4 "," 5 "," 6 ") and e = f`, and so on until d ends

`d` itself is collected in a separate cycle by means of another request

The problem is that d (in any case, `${# d}` shows like this) is not zeroed, although unset d is written at the beginning of the loop

And after several iterations, the `Argument list too long` error starts appearing.

How can I correctly zero out the variable before each iteration?

Whole function:

```
function getPosItems(){
    unset items

    while read item ; do 
        items+='"'$item'",'
    done <<< $(mysql -sN $localConnect -e"select item from posJournal where pricelist=$PRICELISTID $LIMIT")

    q="select price, item from trm_in_pricelist_items where item in ("$items"'') and pricelist_id="$PRICELISTID" "
    echo $(date +%T)' '$CASHID" "$LIMIT
    
    while read posprice positem; do 
        mysql -sN $localConnect -e"update posJournal set posPrice='"$posprice"' where item='"$positem"' and pricelist="$PRICELISTID""
    done <<< $(mysql -sN -uuser -h$POSIP -Dukmclient -p$POSPASS -e"""$q""")
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAuHx.jpg

Comment: Is `d` and `items` the same thing? Why do you say that "unset d is written at the beginning of the loop" when `unset items` is at the beginning of the function and not part of the loop? Is this function itself called in a loop and that's why you believe it should clear `items` repeatedly instead of just once?

Comment: In my opinion, the more you do in MySQL, the more efficient your code. Why don't you try to do something like `SELECT a FROM b WHERE c IN (SELECT item FROM posJournal WHERE pricelist=$PRICELISTID $LIMIT) AND e = f` in only one MySQL statement with a subquery in without iterate in bash?

Comment: d and items are same, yes. This function is called from another loop

Comment: I can't use subqueries, because first with first query I get values from local DB, and with second - from outer DB

Comment: @Emma: MySQL supports federated tables (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create.html), which may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

I replaced `q="query"` with `echo query > *.sql` and `mysql -e"$q"` with `mysql < *.sql` in second query in function

```
function getPosItems(){
    unset items
    local items
    while read item ; do 
        items+='"'$item'",'
    done <<< $(mysql -sN $localConnect -e"select item from posJournal where pricelist=$PRICELISTID $LIMIT")
    echo "select concat(price,' ',item) from trm_in_pricelist_items where item in ("$items"'') and pricelist_id="$PRICELISTID" " > $CASHID'.sql'
    echo $(date +%T)' '$CASHID" "$LIMIT
    while read posprice positem; do 
        mysql -sN $localConnect -e"update posJournal set posPrice='"$posprice"' where item='"$positem"' and pricelist="$PRICELISTID""
    done <<< $(mysql -sN -uuser -h$POSIP -Dukmclient -p$POSPASS < $CASHID'.sql')
}
```